Supporting ReST with ApolloServer startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler
I am running Apollo Server v4 in Lambda and locally.  I want the same process/lambda to service to GraphQL and ReST requests.
Locally, the following does exactly what I want:
app.use(cors(), express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello World!`);
});
app.use("/graphql", expressMiddleware(apolloServer));

On the Lambda side, I am using dougmoscrop/serverless-http and startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler, but the way I am merging them together is, well, revolting.  At the very top level, there is this pile:
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const handler = event.path.startsWith("/api") ? restHandler : graphqlHandler;
  return handler(event, context, callback);
};

This seems like a very natural use, and it works so cleanly in the non-serverless (“serverful”?) world, that I cannot believe that there is no better way.
